# `dict.fromkeys` without values as references to the same object

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a dictionary with `Locks` as values, but I can't use `dict.fromkeys` because it creates only one Lock and multiple references:

```py
my_dict = dict.fromkeys(list_of_keys, Lock())
```

So I do it like:

```py
my_dict = dict((my_key,Lock()) for my_key in list_of_keys)
```

But I wonder if it's possible to use `dict.fromkeys` in any way,

Comment: No, you can only use `dict.fromkeys()` if you want the same value in every element.

Comment: You can also use dictionary comprehenssion

Comment: No, not it isn't.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve that you think you need `dict.fromkeys()` for?

Comment: Related: [How do I initialize a dictionary of empty lists in Python?](/q/11509721/4518341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. `dict.fromkeys()` puts the same value (same object) for each element.

But at least, you could use a dict comprehension to make it look nicer:

```
my_dict = {my_key: Lock() for my_key in list_of_keys}
```